# Jolt Transformation - getting last element by field Sequence

Tags: json, jolt

Say I have the following Json:

```json
{
  "collection": [
    {
      "sequence": 1,
      "value": "event1"
    },
    {
      "sequence": 2,
      "value": "event2"
    },
    {
      "sequence": 3,
      "value": "event3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Given that the array is not guaranteed to be sorted by "sequence", how do I extract the element that has the highest value of "sequence"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the sub-objects of the **`"collection"`** array might be sorted by the **sequence** values by putting them as indexes for reformed array (call **`"objectWithHighestSequence"`**) such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "collection": {
        "*": "objectWithHighestSequence[@(0,sequence)]"
      }
    }
  },
  {
   // only pick the last object after sorting within the shift transformation
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=lastElement(@(1,objectWithHighestSequence))"
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: That's great, thanks. Is it possible to sort the array starting from index 1 rather than 0 to avoid the creation of null elements in the resulting array? i.e. something like "*": "objectWithHighestSequence[@(1,sequence)]" or similar?

Comment: Hi @LinusEriksson , you're welcome, best wishes. Wonder why do we need to avoid to null elements, since we're already not interested with them while getting the last object. Btw, the zero in `@(0,sequence)` stands for level where the `sequence` stays, so "objectWithHighestSequence" disappears in case of using `@(1,sequence)`.